# Byte array from TS not recognized in C# controller

Tags: c#, multithreading, angular, typescript, asynchronous

In my typescript I have file upload where I take file data like this

```
 var data = Array.prototype.map.call(view, function (byte: any) {
            return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join('');
```

Then I proceed to save it to JSON with other variables like this

```
that.fileJSON = { "Filename": parts[0], "Extension": "." + parts[1], "Data": data, "TripId": that.newTripId, "TypeId": 1 };
```

And then I'm sending it to c# controller which awaits

```
[FromBody]Docs
```

Where Docs look like this

```
 public class Docs
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        public int TypeId {get;set;}
        public int TripId { get; set; } 

    }
```

Everything works when uploading 300kb image, but when trying to upload over 1mb image I'm not getting any object in my c# controller, then I get null exception.

Can it be that it doesn't "complete" data variable , because its async?

If so, any ideas how can I await it?

Thanks.

I think the problem is here , console.log doesn't print out the correct object, 
instead it shows [object Object]

```
   postFile(newFile : any) {

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        console.log(newFile);

        return this.http.post('api/Docs/PostDocs/', newFile, options).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're running over the max request length.

Comment: @Amy could you elaborate please? Not sure what do you mean by that:)

Comment: Google "web api max request size"

Comment: I've added [DisableRequestSizeLimit]  on the c# controller. 

Nothing changed. I think the file is too small (~1mb) to hit limits?

Comment: @Amy edited the post, maybe now you can see where the problem is?